# ¿Puedo hacer que fetch no funcione en forma asyncronica?

Tags: fetch

Tengo esta función que me lee con fetch las URL que le paso, para luego analizarlas. El problema que tengo es que al ser "asincrónico" el código JS sigue ejecutando las demas funciones "pero" esas funciones dependen de los datos que trae la funcion
donde tengo la funcion "fetch"

Como hago para que fetch trabaje sincronico? o sea que hasta  que no termine de leer la url no devuelva el control del código que en este ejemplo sería "console.log('Continua...')?
gracias.

```
function leer(cId) {
    fetch(URL + cId, OPTIONS)
    .then((r) => {
        if (r.ok) return r.text();
        else throw new Error(r.status);
    })
    .then((data) => {
      const aData_ = data.split(/\r|\n/);
      const aData = aData_.map((e) => e.trim());
      analizarArray(aData, cId);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e.status);
    });
}
leer('http:...')
console.log('Continua...')
```

Comment: Especialmente hoy en día, con todo el auge de herramientas como RXJS en javascript/typescript y los streams y flux en Java (y seguro que otros lenguajes tienen sus cosas también, yo principalmente trabajo con esto y es lo que conozco)... creo que lo correcto aquí sería que aprendas a trabajar de manera asíncrona en vez de buscar maneras de evitarlo. Si insistes en evitarlo, declara tu función como `async function leer(...` y usa `const response = await fetch(...)`. Pero pienso que es un error insistir en evitar la programación asíncrona hoy en día y tener el código lleno de `await`s queda mal.

Comment: NO es una buena idea lo que intentas hacer. ¿Por qué? Porque Javascript es de un solo hilo, y si bloqueas el hilo principal hasta que la petición se procese, todo quedará bloqueado. ¿Qué consecuencias tiene eso? Entre otras cosas, una pésima UX (experiencia de usuario). Ante un código que está bloqueado, el usuario empezará a darle a los botones, intentará recargar, abrirá/cerrará el navegador ... hasta que se harte y desinstale tu aplicación optando por otra que haga lo mismo ... o te llamará para quejarse del pésimo programa que le has entregado, etc. Es sólo un ejemplo entre otras cosas.

Comment: Gracias a ambos por contestar, el porque necesito hacer eso es porque solo lo usaré yo al script nadie mas, necesito sacar datos de esas paginas y si lo hago asincronicamente no me sirve, tengo que leer pagina a pagina y sacar datos. perdieron la base de datos y todos esos datos estan plasmados en difernetes paginas estáticas.